# Django models, how to set object owner while saving

Tags: python, django

Friend model:

```
# Friend model
class Friend(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friend_friend')
```

**How it should work:** User adds friend and then Django sets owner to current_user

**Question:** How to set owner to current user when a new Friend object is being saved?

Comment: Did you try assigning to the attribute?

Comment: Same way you assign to every other attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a little change to your model:

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="owners_friend")
```

and your views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/yourloginurl/')
def save_newfriend(request):
   owner = request.user
   # process friend_form_data       
   new_friend = owner.owners_friend.create(friend=friend_form_data)
```

this way, you dont need to assign the `owner` explicitly since you are creating Friend from owner's object so to speak